# CakePHP 3.X Multiple Model association

Tags: php, cakephp, save, polymorphic-associations, cakephp-3.x

Currently I have 'posts' and 'users' models associated to an 'attachments' model, everything works perfectly execpt for the fact that I need to put a hidden input in every form telling CakePHP which model I'm going to use, just like the code below:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($post); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create a new Post</legend>

    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('content');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('attachments.0.model', ['default' => 'Post']);
        echo $this->Form->control('attachments.0.image_url');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('attachments.1.model', ['default' => 'Post']);
        echo $this->Form->control('attachments.1.image_url');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Save Post')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Is there a way to tell Cake which Attachment.model I'm going to use for each model/controller? Or this is the right way to do it?

Comment: According to [Creating Inputs for Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) you can create inputs for associated data like this: `echo $this->Form->control('tags.0.id');` Though I think I misunderstood the question. You're trying to edit the `Attachments` associated to `Posts` right? If so, I can write an better explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the respective table classes `beforeSave` and/or `beforeMarshal` events/callbacks to modify the attachments data with respect to the current table (model), ie inject the table (model) name.

Depending on when you want to things to apply you could use only of them (only/before marshalling > use `beforeMarshal`, only saving > use `beforeSave`), or even both.

Here's a basic example that unconditionally injects the current table name both in the marshalling as well as the saving stage:

```
use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\Event\Event;

// ...

public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    if (isset($data['attachments']) &&
        is_array($data['attachments'])
    ) {
        $alias = $this->registryAlias();
        foreach ($data['attachments'] as &$attachment) {
            $attachment['model'] = $alias;
        }
    }
}

public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    $attachments = $entity->get('attachments');
    if (is_array($attachments)) {
        $alias = $this->registryAlias();
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            $attachment->set('model', $alias);
        }
    }
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Lifecycle Callbacks > beforeSave](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave)**